# SQL name string matching -sql server

Tags: sql-server, string

I have a table with data in the form

```
Date    Amount  Payer
04/01/2021  50  LARRY BURNS
16/01/2021  46  JOHN SMITH
15/01/2021  35  SUSAN ARTHUR
14/01/2021  28  S. ARTHUR
13/01/2021  21  JO SMITH
12/01/2021  13  LARRY BURNS
11/01/2021  6   SUSAN ARTHUR
```

I also have another table with data in the form

```
ID  Customer Name   Customer Type
10001   LARRY BURNS      CU
10002   JOHN SMITH       CU
10003   SUSAN ARTHUR     CU
```

The first table which is a transactions table does not have a foreign key to reference the ID from the customer. The only information provided is the Payer column which includes inconsistently spelled names of customers. Is it possible to do some form of 'name matching' as a pseudo-join to allow retrieval of the customer name and ID?

Ideally in the form:

```
    Date    Amount  Payer      Customer Name      ID
04/01/2021  50  LARRY BURNS     LARRY BURNS     10001
16/01/2021  46  JOHN SMITH       JOHN SMITH     10002
15/01/2021  35  SUSAN ARTHUR    SUSAN ARTHUR    10003
14/01/2021  28  S. ARTHUR      SUSAN ARTHUR     10003
13/01/2021  21  JO SMITH       JOHN SMITH       10002
12/01/2021  13  LARRY BURNS    LARRY BURNS      10001
11/01/2021  6   SUSAN ARTHUR    SUSAN ARTHUR    10003
```

Comment: Not reliably, what if another customer is called `Sam Arthur`, which might be entered as `S. Arthur`? And people can have the exact same name too

Comment: Willing to put in an allowance for inaccuracies

Comment: Depending on your "allowance" and your server version, you've got the various `TRIM` functions, `SUBSTRING`, `STRING_SPLIT`, `LIKE` and `SOUNDEX` to cobble together a manual approach. That's about it; T-SQL is not a language for serious string processing/data cleaning. Note also that "Jo Smith" might be quite annoyed to get bills intended for "John Smith"; when it comes to financial data especially you really want to change the processes to allow for exact matches, since estimated invoicing isn't a sustainable practice (allowing for the fact that this is probably just an example, of course).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I think John Smith would be more annoyed they *aren't* getting those bills, and a bailiff shows up at the door

Comment: @HoneyBadger: I expect the bailiff to show up at the door of Joe Smith (who is unrelated to either one) with the kind of system proposed here. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're willing to have an allowance for differences, you could try something like the following:

```
DECLARE @Payer table (
    [Date] date, Amount decimal(18,2), Payer varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO @Payer VALUES
    ( '01/04/2021', 50, 'LARRY BURNS' ),
    ( '01/16/2021', 46, 'JOHN SMITH' ),
    ( '01/15/2021', 35, 'SUSAN ARTHUR' ),
    ( '01/14/2021', 28, 'S. ARTHUR' ),
    ( '01/13/2021', 21, 'JO SMITH' ),
    ( '01/12/2021', 13, 'LARRY BURNS' ),
    ( '01/11/2021', 6 , 'SUSAN ARTHUR' );

DECLARE @Customer table (
    ID int, CustomerName varchar(50), CustomerType varchar(2)
);
INSERT INTO @Customer VALUES
    ( 10001, 'LARRY BURNS', 'CU' ),
    ( 10002, 'JOHN SMITH', 'CU' ),
    ( 10003, 'SUSAN ARTHUR', 'CU' );

SELECT
    [Date],
    Amount,
    Payer,
    ID,
    CustomerName
FROM @Payer AS payer
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT TOP 1
        ID,
        CustomerName
    FROM @Customer AS c
    WHERE
        c.CustomerName = payer.Payer
        OR
        DIFFERENCE ( payer.Payer, c.CustomerName ) >= 3
        OR
        DIFFERENCE ( c.CustomerName, payer.Payer ) >= 3

) AS customer;
```

Returns

```
+------------+--------+--------------+-------+--------------+
|    Date    | Amount |    Payer     |  ID   | CustomerName |
+------------+--------+--------------+-------+--------------+
| 2021-01-04 | 50.00  | LARRY BURNS  | 10001 | LARRY BURNS  |
| 2021-01-16 | 46.00  | JOHN SMITH   | 10002 | JOHN SMITH   |
| 2021-01-15 | 35.00  | SUSAN ARTHUR | 10003 | SUSAN ARTHUR |
| 2021-01-14 | 28.00  | S. ARTHUR    | 10003 | SUSAN ARTHUR |
| 2021-01-13 | 21.00  | JO SMITH     | 10002 | JOHN SMITH   |
| 2021-01-12 | 13.00  | LARRY BURNS  | 10001 | LARRY BURNS  |
| 2021-01-11 | 6.00   | SUSAN ARTHUR | 10003 | SUSAN ARTHUR |
+------------+--------+--------------+-------+--------------+
```